# include/GL/glu.h: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, opengl, g++

My volume rendering code works fine in window 7 but when I try to migrate Ubuntu 14.04,
there are compile errors. Can anybody help me? In my system, there are glew glut gl glu library already installed.

Makefile:

```
    CC = g++

    OFLAG = -o

    CFLAGS = -c -Wall -g -DDEBUG

    LIB = -lGLEW -lglut -lGL -lGLU

    LIB_DIR = -L"./lib"

    INC_DIR = -I"./include"


    all: main.o

        $(CC) $(OFLAG) main main.o  $(LIB_DIR) $(LIB)

    main.o: main.cpp

        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp $(INC_DIR)

    clean:
        rm main.o main
```

==================================================================

```
    g++ -c -Wall -g -DDEBUG main.cpp -I"./include"
    In file included from ./include/GL/glew.h:1180:0,
                     from main.cpp:3:
    ./include/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                                   ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    ./include/GL/glu.h:68:79: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
    ./include/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     void APIENTRY gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *tess,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                                   ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    ./include/GL/glu.h:78:79: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
    ./include/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     void APIENTRY gluNurbsCallback(GLUnurbs *nobj,GLenum which,void (CALLBACK *fn)());
                                                                               ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    ./include/GL/glu.h:94:75: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
    ./include/GL/glu.h:96:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUquadricErrorProc)(GLenum);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:97:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessBeginProc)(GLenum);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:98:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEdgeFlagProc) (GLboolean);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:99:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessVertexProc)(void *);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:100:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEndProc)(void);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:101:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessErrorProc)(GLenum);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:102:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessCombineProc)(GLdouble[3],void*[4],GLfloat[4],void**);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:103:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessBeginDataProc)(GLenum,void *);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:104:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEdgeFlagDataProc) (GLboolean,void *);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:105:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessVertexDataProc)(void *,void *);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:106:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessEndDataProc)(void *);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:107:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessErrorDataProc)(GLenum,void *);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:108:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUtessCombineDataProc)(GLdouble[3],void*[4],GLfloat[4],void**,void*);
                            ^
    ./include/GL/glu.h:109:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
     typedef void (CALLBACK *GLUnurbsErrorProc)(GLenum);
                            ^
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

==============================================================

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform2.hpp>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using glm::mat4;
using glm::vec3;
```

Comment: Show the code around where you include the files.

Comment: @user3413642 it says it was included on line 3 of main, what's in line 1 and 2?

Comment: //#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

Line 1 is above and line 2 is blank

Comment: well it looks to me that `CALLBACK` got defined to something although it shouldn't. From where did you copy the glew and glu headers and why aren't you using the system ones in `/usr/include/GL` (presuming you installed libglew-dev )

Comment: I used the one form Ubuntu. I used apt-get to install glu and glew is installed using this http://glew.sourceforge.net/build.html information.

Comment: @user3413642 yeah, but that's not the one you use right? you are using the ones added by `-I"./include"` aren't you?

Comment: PeterT, Thank you so much. You are right! Really appreciate~ :)